# Attribute mysteriously getting set to id of 1

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, error-handling

I have an object that is apparently randomly getting set to an id of 1 and the source of where this is happening is unknown in the codebase. Could be on an update attributes for a user for which school is associated.

How can I raise an error or otherwise log when this happens so I can track it down and resolve it?

Below is a first attempt but doesn't seem to take into account `update_attributes`

```
belongs_to :foo_school, :foreign_key => 'school_id'

def foo_school=(foo_school)
  begin
    raise "Found" if foo_school == FooSchool.find(1)
  rescue Exception => e
    # Track it down through the stack trace
    Rails.logger.error e
  ensure
    write_attribute(:foo_school, foo_school)
  end
end
```

Comment: Stack traces? Full code? What does foo_school contains? It's really hard to understand what's happening here with only this much information.

Comment: That is in the scope of a model that belongs_to a FooSchool. It doesn't matter what FooSchool contains other than an id. All I want to do is raise an error when an associated model, FooSchool, is updated with an id of 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An observer can do this for you. What you do with this observer is up to you.

`$ rails g observer Oddity`

Add this in `config/application.rb` (search for "observer" in that file, there's an example by default).
`config.active_record.observers = :oddity_observer`

```
class OddityObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
  observe :foo

  def after_update(record)
    raise "Boom" if record.id == 1
  end 
end
```